# iOS: RestKit Alternative for Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, ios9, xcode7, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to do away with Objective-C Libraries.

Is there a RestKit alternative for Swift that provides Core Data entity mapping that maps serialized response objects directly to managed objects?

I was hoping Alamofire in conjunction with SwiftyJSON would solve this problem, but that's not the case.

Has anyone tried Siesta:  https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/ ?

Please share any alternatives.  Thanks.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but an interested question; why are you trying to replace objective-c with Swift if the obj-c is currently working? I'm facing the same issue at the moment, I have 20ish obj-c pods but am moving my codebase to Swift!

Comment: I am trying to free my project out of Objective-C dependency completely.  This provides easier on-boarding and we can take junior-mid level developers that have no prior experience with Obj-C.   BTW, there isn't anything like RESTKit for Swift.  In fact, I am trying to avoid using any 3rd party libraries.  Currently, I switched over to Alamofire and SwiftyJSON, which I hope to get rid of in the near future and  use Apple's native APIs without any wrappers.

Comment: no one try an alternative?

Comment: How about https://github.com/SyncDB/Sync

Comment: Argo with Alamofire should do the trick.